# Matplotlib animate annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to animate a line plot with annotation, but cannot figure why the annotation is not being animated.
This is what I have tried so far, just cannot figure what's going wrong here.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

class LineChartRace:
    def __init__(self, total_casen):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 9))
        self.x, self.y = list(total_casen.index), np.array(total_casen)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(total_casen.index, total_casen, c='r')
        self.annot = self.ax.annotate(self.x[-1],
                    (mdates.date2num(self.x[-1]), self.y[-1]), 
                    xytext=(1, 7),
                    textcoords='offset points',
                    size=17)
        # plt.show()
        
    def update(self, num):
        self.line.set_data(self.x[:num], self.y[:num])
        x_co, y_co = mdates.date2num(self.x[num]), self.y[num]
        
        self.annot.set_position((x_co, y_co))
        self.annot.set_text(self.x[num])
       
        return self.line, self.annot

    def animate(self):
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update, len(self.x),
                              interval=25, blit=False)
        plt.show()

date = pd.date_range(start='2021/01/01', end='2021/05/01')
total_casen = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': date,
    'case': np.arange(0, len(date))
    }).set_index('date').loc[:, 'case']
                    
lcr = LineChartRace(total_casen)
lcr.animate()
```

plotting the initial static plot works fine

[image]

EDIT:
Looks like the `textcoords='offset points'` was the culprit here.
I don't have any clue why, would appreciate any explanatin.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying part of `matplotlib` -> animations must exist outside of classes - I do not know why this is but I believe it is because the animation object must exist perpetually and not just in the context of the class. Anyway, here is a solution:

```
class LineChartRace:
    def __init__(self, total_casen):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 9))
        self.x, self.y = list(total_casen.index), np.array(total_casen)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(total_casen.index, total_casen, c='r')
        self.annot = self.ax.annotate(self.x[-1],
                    (mdates.date2num(self.x[-1]), self.y[-1]), 
                    xytext=(1, 7),
                    textcoords='offset points',
                    size=17)
        # plt.show()
        
    def update(self, num):
        self.line.set_data(self.x[:num], self.y[:num])
        x_co, y_co = mdates.date2num(self.x[num]), self.y[num]
        
        self.annot.set_position((x_co, y_co))
        self.annot.set_text(self.x[num])
       
        return self.line, self.annot

    def animate(self):
        # return the function instead of allocating it to a local variable
        # do not use plt.show either since this will be done later

        return animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update, len(self.x),
                              interval=25, blit=False)
        

date = pd.date_range(start='2021/01/01', end='2021/05/01')
total_casen = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': date,
    'case': np.arange(0, len(date))
    }).set_index('date').loc[:, 'case']
                    
lcr = LineChartRace(total_casen)
animate_function = lcr.animate()
animate_function()
plt.show()
```